# Pass the string and integer in HTML

Tags: python

I am writing a python program to send email. I want to pass a string to the html tag. 
Here is the code

```
    Item= ['hi', 'bye']
    I = Item.pop(1) 
    Age=67
    me=abc@gmail.com
    you=bba@gmail.com
    msg= MIMEMultipart('alternative') 
    msg['subject'] = "test email"
    msg['from'] = me
    msg['to'] = you
    text= "happy birthday"
    html = '''\
            <html>
              <body> 
                 <p>   %s</p>
                  <p> it's your %s birthday</p>
                </body></html>
                                 ''' %str(I, Age) 
     part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain') 
     part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html') 
     msg.attach(part1) 
     msg.attach(part2) 
     s= smtplib.SMTP("hostname", port=12) 
     s.sendemail(me, you, msg.as_string()) 
     s.quit()
```

I am getting the below error.

```
TypeError : decoding to str: need a byte-like object, int found
```

Comment: HTML is text. Your question is only about string formatting (tag removed).

Answer (score 1):

Your error message doesn't match you code snippet (not for me at least - python 3.6.x) and has a few obvious syntax errors. You should take care of posting a *proper* [mcve].

But anyway: I don't know what you expect by calling `str(I, Age)`, but it's both wrong (please read the doc for `str()`) and useless (format operations will take care of formatting, that's what they are for.

IOW, you just want (simplified for readability):

```
html = "<p>%s</p> <p>%s</p>" % (I, Age)
```

or preferably:

```
html = "<p>{}</p> <p>{}</p>".format(I, Age)
```

Answer (score 1):

`str` is used to convert (cast) a variable from one type to another.

```py
>>> a = 1
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
>>> b = str(a)
>>> type(b)
<type 'str'>
```

Here you are passing multiple arguments to `str`, but your `I` variable is already a string, only your `Age` variable needs to be converted to a string.

```py
>>> "%s, I'm %s years old" % ('Hi', str(39))
"Hi, I'm 39 years old"
```

**EDIT: seems even that conversion is not required, thanks to @brunodesthuilliers for his remark.**

```py
>>> "%s, I'm %s years old" % ('Hi', 39)
"Hi, I'm 39 years old"
```

**/EDIT**

But in fact, even that is not really useful. You can call the `format` method of a string object to do the casting for you. Instead of printf-ilke format specifiers (`%d`, `%s`, etc), use braces, and the index of the parameter you pass to format.

```py
>>> "{0}, I'm {1} years old".format('Hi', 39)
"Hi, I'm 39 years old"
```

You can also use f-strings since python 3.6, and just put the variable names between braces directly in a string with a leading `f` (hence the f-string name):

```py
>>> I = 'Hi'
>>> Age = 39
>>> f"{I}, I'm {Age} years old"
"Hi, I'm 39 years old"
```

Here a good article to learn more about [string formatting in Python](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

Comment: Actually, even with old style string formatting (with '%s' placeholder and "%s"), you don't need to "cast" anything to string - it works the same as `str.format()` on this account.

Comment: At least a sensible answer anyway, and well explained.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: Edited, thanks for your remark.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a format function instead of `%` like below:

```
html = '''\
    <html>
      <body> 
         <p>   {s}</p>
          <p> it's your {s} birthday</p>
        </body></html>
                         ''' .format(s=I + " " + str(Age))
```

Comment: What's the point of doing string concatenation to pass things to `str.format()` exactly ???

Comment: I just wanted to show a replacement for this statement: `%str(I, Age)`...

Comment: I'm afraid that like King11 already said, you are not providing any value by downvoting answers that actually solve the original question which was about getting rid of type error, not about best practices in string formatting.

Comment: Could you be kind enough to try and understand what the OP is __really__ trying to get as result ?

Comment: Actually yes, I'll do better next time. Thanks.